# Where are Windows Messages such as WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_COMMAND, and WM_CLOSE defined in the win32 C/C++ API?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, include

I'm running through [theForger's Win32 API Programming Tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/). On [page 4](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/message_loop.html) he suggests it would be handy to find the list of #define statements in the API header files which list all the WM_* messages. I decided it probably would be worth my while to take a gander at them all, so I tried to find them, but was unsuccessful.

If anyone could just send the name of the appropriate file and possibly its location relative to "windows.h" my way, it would be much appreciated. I have been rummaging around in my compiler's "include" folder for quite a while now, and for the life of me I can't find it, so I figured before I go ahead and look at every single include file (there are 294 of them), I should ask you guys, since I'm sure someone knows already.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just as a general suggestion, a grep utility will be a big help (even Window's own "find" utility will work, even if it's not great).  Also, IDE's will generally have some command to go to the definition/declaration of an identifier. The Free Visual C++ Express will do.

Comment: You've accepted Charles answer which is indeed a correct answer to your direct question. The real value is to be found in @Michael's advice. Learn how to use grep.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for that tip.

Comment: grep? That's really a last resort. You should really prefer the methods offered by your IDE. It's much better when it comes to understanding macro's, knowing what files are part of your project, etcetera.

Comment: I tend to prefer doing things at command line, so I'm not familiar enough with any IDE to really use these features. And anyway, why not use grep? All I'm doing is taking a look at what is in the header files. grep speeds up my search for a particular item. Simplicity over high-level functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `winuser.h` in the platform SDK include folder.